# Obtaining dictionary names in a yaml file

Tags: python, list, dictionary, yaml

i have a yaml file like the below:

```
Histograms:
  zee: 
    bins: {"fix": [55, 0.1 ,35e3]}  
    Title: "é isso ai"
    Xlabel: "como assim" 
    Ylabel: "Z #rightarrow e^{+}e^{-}"
    ymax: 35e3
    ymim: 0.1  
    color: 4 #root.kAzure+3 
    scale: 1.0

  ztautau: 
    ymax: 35e3
    ymim: 0.1    
    ymaxp: 1.19
    ymimp: 0.81
    label: "Z #rightarrow e^{+}e^{-}"     
    color: ""

  ttbar: 
    ymax: 35e3
    ymim: 0.1    
    ymaxp: 1.19
    ymimp: 0.81
    label: "Z #rightarrow e^{+}e^{-}"    
    
  wplustaunu: 
     bins: {"fix": [55, 0.1 ,35e3]}  
     Title: "é isso ai"
     Xlabel: "como assim" 
     Ylabel: "Z #rightarrow e^{+}e^{-}"
     ymax: 35e3
     ymim: 0.1  
     color: "root.kAzure+3" 
     scale: 1.0
```

And i need to obtain the folowing strings through a loop: zee,ztautau,ttbar,wplustaunu (they are the title of the dictionaries, i guess?). I mean i need they through a loop (in python) because i need to work with files that have lots of dictionaries like that, so witting them down myself is not a good choice. But i am been working on this for some time and was unable to figure out a solution, so if anyone can help me or point me some reference, i would be extremely grateful.

The output that i want is:

> zee
> ztautau
> ttbar
> wplusenu

I dont want anything more, just these data. Is it possible?.

Thanks for the attention!

Comment: Show us  what you expect to have as output.  Getting the strings is easy, but I presume there's more to it. Do you want the sub-entries as nested dictionaries?

Comment: And, by the way, there is a YAML parser for Python:  https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to filter out what is a dictionary under Histograms.  You can do with a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/#examples).

```
from yaml import safe_load as yload

di = yload("""    Histograms:
      zee: 
        bins: {"fix": [55, 0.1 ,35e3]}  
        Title: "é isso ai"
        Xlabel: "como assim" 
        Ylabel: "Z #rightarrow e^{+}e^{-}"
        ymax: 35e3
        ymim: 0.1  
        color: 4 #root.kAzure+3 
        scale: 1.0
    
      ztautau: 
        ymax: 35e3
        ymim: 0.1    
        ymaxp: 1.19
        ymimp: 0.81
        label: "Z #rightarrow e^{+}e^{-}"     
        color: ""
    
      ttbar: 
        ymax: 35e3
        ymim: 0.1    
        ymaxp: 1.19
        ymimp: 0.81
        label: "Z #rightarrow e^{+}e^{-}"    
        
      wplustaunu: 
         bins: {"fix": [55, 0.1 ,35e3]}  
         Title: "é isso ai"
         Xlabel: "como assim" 
         Ylabel: "Z #rightarrow e^{+}e^{-}"
         ymax: 35e3
         ymim: 0.1  
         color: "root.kAzure+3" 
         scale: 1.0   
""")

dict_of_dict = {k:v for k,v in di.get("Histograms",{}).items() if isinstance(v, dict)}

for k,v in dict_of_dict.items():  
    print(f"\n{k}:{v}")
```

#### output:

```
zee:{'bins': {'fix': [55, 0.1, '35e3']}, 'Title': 'é isso ai', 'Xlabel': 'como assim', 'Ylabel': 'Z #rightarrow e^{+}e^{-}', 'ymax': '35e3', 'ymim': 0.1, 'color': 4, 'scale': 1.0}

ztautau:{'ymax': '35e3', 'ymim': 0.1, 'ymaxp': 1.19, 'ymimp': 0.81, 'label': 'Z #rightarrow e^{+}e^{-}', 'color': ''}

ttbar:{'ymax': '35e3', 'ymim': 0.1, 'ymaxp': 1.19, 'ymimp': 0.81, 'label': 'Z #rightarrow e^{+}e^{-}'}

wplustaunu:{'bins': {'fix': [55, 0.1, '35e3']}, 'Title': 'é isso ai', 'Xlabel': 'como assim', 'Ylabel': 'Z #rightarrow e^{+}e^{-}', 'ymax': '35e3', 'ymim': 0.1, 'color': 'root.kAzure+3', 'scale': 1.0}
```

Just the keys, Sir?

`[k for k,v in di.get("Histograms",{}).items() if isinstance(v, dict)]`

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the only output i want is something like: zee , ztautau , ttbar and wplusenu. I don't want the information inside them.

Comment: @Daumann The necessary modification to the answer is minimal.

Comment: Yes, now i got it. thanks soo much  @JL Peyret  and timgeb.